# Why can't use tracert command in batch file

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, batch

I try to use Tracert command in batch file but its not working!

```
@echo off
title Network Tracer
Set /p Host= Please Enter Hostname or IP Address: 
if defined Host (
   tracert %Host% >output.txt
)
```

I need store tracert output to text file.
Is there a way to use tracert command in batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Tracert command from Powershell and its worked!

```
@echo off
title Network Tracer
Set /p Host= Please Enter Hostname or IP Address: 
if defined Host (
   powershell -Command tracert -d %Host% >output.txt
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the command in Powershell.
If i run this command in cmd.exe no file will be created - under Powershell it is working like expected.

```
@echo off
title Network Tracer
Set /p Host= Please Enter Hostname or IP Address: 
if defined Host (
   tracert %Host% >output.txt
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did different?

Comment: I was testing the Code and it is working - the file will be created.